# Deserialization json with field-type-container by GSON

Tags: java, gson, json-deserialization

I has a json with field-type container like

```
var inputJson = """
                {
                    "stringField1": {
                        "string": "stringField1Value"
                    }
                }
                """;
```

Also i has a class

```
package model;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class SimpleClass {
    private Long longField;
    private String stringField1;
    private String stringField2;
}
```

How can i deserialize this json to SimpleClass by GSON? Are there any default settings for Gson or GsonBuilder?

I was tried configure GsonBuilder but failed

Comment: field type can be any primitive type or classname(with packaages)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a quick implementation, I suggest using `org.json.JSONObject`, and not go into the hassle of setting up a GSON dataclass.

Just call the constructor [`JSONObject(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#JSONObject(java.lang.String)) with the json string. You will get an object than can be accessed like this:

```java
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(inputJson);
String string1 = o.getJSONObject("stringField1").getString("string1");
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative to creating a deserializer to handle complete deserialization of `SimpleClass` (as suggested in [the other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75568598)), you could create a custom deserializer or type adaper which unwraps the string value, and then place Gson's [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) annotation on the `stringField1` field to only customize deserialization for that field:

```java
class UnwrappingStringAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {
    // No-args constructor called by Gson
    public UnwrappingStringAdapter() { }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, String value) throws IOException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public String read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        in.beginObject();
        String name = in.nextName();
        String value;

        if (name.equals("string")) {
            value = in.nextString();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected property: " + name);
        }

        in.endObject();
        return value;
    }
}
```

And then place the `@JsonAdapter` annotation on the field:

```java
class SimpleClass {
    @JsonAdapter(UnwrappingStringAdapter.class)
    private String stringField1;
}
```